# jQuery validation in Bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am using bootstrap validation within bootstrap tabs and I have it working for the most part.

However, I am using this piece of code to take you to the closest error it finds.

```
        $("#application").validate({
            ignore: "",
            rules: {
                resumeField: {
                    required: true,
                    require_from_group: [1,".required-group"]
                },
                resumePaste: {
                    required: function()
                    {
                        CKEDITOR.instances['resumePaste'].updateElement();
                    },
                    require_from_group: [1,".required-group"],
                }
            },
            messages: {
                resumeField: "Please select your Resume",
                resumePaste: "Please enter the contents of your resume"
            },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                var tab = $(element).closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');
                $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                CKEDITOR.instances['resumePaste'].updateElement();
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function() {

                return false;

            }

        });
```

Here is the HTML markup for the tabs:

```
<div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-heading">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
           <li class="active"><a href="#resumeTab" data-toggle="tab">Step 1 - Résumé</a></li>
           <li><a href="#questionsTab" data-toggle="tab">Step 2 - Questions</a></li>
           <li><a href="#proficienciesTab" data-toggle="tab">Step 3 - Proficiencies</a></li>
           <li><a href="#submitTab" data-toggle="tab">Step 4 - Submit</a></li>
        </ul>
        </span>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
           <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="resumeTab">
              <div class="page-header">
                 <h4><small>Select Résumé</small></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                 <span class="input-group-btn">
                 <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                 <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Browse <input type="file" name="resumeFile" id="resumeFile">
                 </span>
                 </span>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="resumeField" class="required_group" id="resumeField">
              </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /input-group -->
              <br />
              <center>
                 <span class="text-primary">
                    <h3>- OR -</h3>
                 </span>
              </center>

              <div class="page-header">
                 <h4><small>Paste Résumé Contents</small></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="col-xs-12 required_group" rows="10" name="resumePaste" id="resumePaste"></textarea>
              <script>
                 CKEDITOR.replace( 'resumePaste' );
              </script>
              </div>
              <br />
              <button type="button" name="progressButton" tabID="questionsTab" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
           </div>
           <div class="tab-pane fade" id="questionsTab">

           <?php $counter = 1; foreach($getApplication->internships->questions as $data){ ?>
           <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Question #<?php echo $counter; ?></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                       <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-5">
                             <h4 class="text-primary"><span name="question"><?php echo $data->question; ?></span></h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-7">
                          <textarea class="col-xs-12 question" rows="6" name="question[<?php echo $data->questionID; ?>]['answer']"></textarea>
                          <input type="hidden" name="question[<?php echo $data->questionID; ?>]['question']" value="<?php echo $data->question; ?>">
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
           <?php $counter++; } ?>

            <button type="button" name="progressButton" tabID="resumeTab" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Previous</button>
            <button type="button" name="progressButton" tabID="proficienciesTab" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>

           </div>
           <div class="tab-pane fade" id="proficienciesTab">

            <button type="button" name="progressButton" tabID="questionsTab" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Previous</button>
            <button type="button" name="progressButton" tabID="submitTab" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
           </div>
           <div class="tab-pane fade" id="submitTab">

            <button type="button" name="progressButton" tabID="proficienciesTab" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Previous</button>
            <button type="submit" value="submit" name="doSubmit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit Application&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-cloud"></i></button>

           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

The issue is, i have 4 tabs and every one it finds an error on it marks it as active which messes it up.

Is there a way to limit the closest() to just 1 instance and not all?

If im on tab 4 and there are errors on 1 and 2, my goal is to just take them to the first error which would be tab 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're going to have to show us more code than that.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where is the HTML markup?  Again, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this issue? I'm having the same problem with the validation of multiple tabs